# How to set authLevel for azure functions using the portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

This piece of documentation references configuring an azure function by way of a file on `D:\home\data` and a local json file.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-triggers-bindings/#apikeys

First of all, where is the `file/source` code when the function is created through the portal dashboard UI, and how can I change those settings?

I'm assuming that this is the case when the service is created through the git method, but I don't see how to change the settings or view the keys through the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

We haven't built portal UI yet for managing these secrets/keys. We'll get to that soon.

So for now, they must be modified manually and that was the intent of that documentation, to show you the underlying details so you could do that if you needed to (until the portal UI is done).

I think the bit the doc left out that you might be missing is that to see the underlying files, you can use the [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service). You can open up Kudu from the Functions portal by selecting "**Function app settings**", hitting the "**Go to App Service Settings**" button, hit the "**Tools**" toolbar button, and launching Kudu from the UI blade.

After you have opened up Kudu on your Function App, you can open the Debug Console on the root of your Function App, allowing you to navigate to the various files the doc mentions. For example **data\functions\secrets** or **site\wwwroot** which is where your function scripts are stored.

Comment: looking at the documentation for kudu - I'm still a bit confused on what it is.  Is it a management tool for azure web applications, or a source control tool, or a log managment tool, or some combination of  those 3?

Comment: Kudu is the engine behind a number of features of Azure Web Apps, including source control based deployment / continuous integration, WebJobs, as well as a set useful debugging tools. Since Azure Functions is built on the same underlying infrastructure, Azure Functions inherits all those awesome capabilities :)